# Array length not working as expected

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i[][][] = new int[3][2][1];
    System.out.println(i[0].length + " " + i[0][0].length);
}
```

The program above seems like it should print "3 2". Instead, it prints "2 1". So it seems [0] refers to the "second dimension" and not the first. Why? How *do* I refer to the first dimension?

i[0][0][0].length doesn't work at all, but gives "int cannot be dereferenced". What am I missing here?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: `System.out.println(i.length + " " + i[0].length);`...

Answer (score 2):

The first dimension is `i`. Let's split it up:

```
int i[][][] = new int[3][2][1];
int j[][] = i[0]
int k[] = j[0] // or i[0][0]
int l = k[0] // or j[0][0] or i[0][0][0]
// the following prints 3 2 1
System.out.println(i.length + " " + i[0].length + " " + i[0][0].length);
```

You say in your comment that `anArray[0]` is the first element. This is right. The first element of a three-dimensional array is a two-dimensional array, which in your case has the length 2.

It might get clearer if you write it another way (yours is considered a little unconventional anyway):

```
int[][][] i = new int[3][2][1];
```

This makes clear that `i` points to a three-dimensional int array. If you want the length of that array (or better said it's first dimension) you'd have to get it via `i`.

Answer (score 2):

`i` is the 3 dimensional array, so `i.length` gives the first size.

`i[0]` is the first one of the 2 dimensional arrays, so `i[0].length` gives the second size.

`i[0][0]` is the first one of the 1 dimensional arrays, so `i[0][0].length` gives the third size.

`i[0][0][0]` is an int, so cannot do `.length` on it.

Answer (score 1):

That is a bit unnatural in Java.

Intuitively, I would interpret this:

```
new int[x][y][z]
```

as being:

```
new ((int[x])[y])[z] // (Array of int[][]) with length z
```

But that is **NOT** true. That is the odd part. It actually really is:

```
new int[x]([y]([z])) // (Array of int[][]) with length x
```

Which means this is an array with length `x`. The array, contains arrays, all of size `y`, and these arrays, contain arrays all of size `z`.

Comment: I never look at arrays by their initialisers, but their use, which is `i[0][1][2]`. This is more intuitive than `i[2][1][0]`, thus arrays are initialised like this. Oh and BTW: Your post doesn't answer the question ;)

Comment: I know, that is the reason why they did that. But then think: what is the difference between: `new int[5][2]` and `new Object[5]`? In the second case, the `Object` part was the type of the array. Where as in the first case, the type of the array was actually: `int[2]`, which is a bit in a messy order, right?